# Using local.xml, I'm getting "Invalid Nesting" errors

Tags: layout, error

With the aim to simplify a lot of our layout XML, I've moved the pertinent parts of our individual files to one local.xml.  Everything works fine.  However, in the logs, I see errors like this:

> 2013-03-05T21:44:53+00:00 DEBUG (7): [INVALID NESTING!] Found: layout/package_update: catalog_product_view | Expecting: layout/db_update: SHORTCUT_uk_popup

The expected `<update handle="SHORTCUT_uk_popup" />` node is in `paypaluk.xml`.  I tried just adding it to the same area of my `local.xml` but didn't fix it.

I could just comment it out but I wanted to understand what the Best Practice way should be.  Could anyone advise?

Comment: Please post the contents of the XML files so that we can have a closer look...

Comment: http://pastebin.com/v8HauF9a  Thanks Simon!

Comment: At the risk of starting a war, local.xml is a horrible practice. There are much more elegant approaches. I'll post an answer when I get in the office.

Comment: This sounds really interessting. Can you post this as an answer and mark it as solution, please?

Comment: @sonassi Have you had a chance to write up why local.xml is horrible practice, sounds interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the message goes away when I uninstall Aoe_Profiler. So not sure if that fixes anything or just hides the message.

Comment: Please mark this answer as a solution.

Answer (score 3):

You are right that aoe_profiler causes the issue. The error you are getting is in relating to profiler 'buckets'.

ref: http://www.fabrizio-branca.de/magento-profiler.html and check the defining buckets section.

```
Varien_Profiler::start(‘<bucketName>’);
```

... code to profile in the bucket ....

```
Varien_Profiler::stop(‘<bucketName>’);
```

Basically what you have is one block defining a starting bucket, then another block inside the first starting a bucket, before the original bucket its closed.

I had this before, and can be safely ignored, unless you are in need to profile the parts in the buckets.

or disable your profiler ;)

It is just noise.
If someone knows better, I stand corrected.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer this als comment, but then it is unreadable.

I pasted your file to my system and ran it, it throw an error and I removed the following lines (I have a CE here):

```
<action method="cachePage">
    <expires></expires>
    <disqualifiers>cart,loggedin</disqualifiers>
    <holecontent>lightspeedcontent/hole/index</holecontent>
</action>
```

and it runs without error.

I think you made a cut&copy error in your `paypaluk.xml`. Please check, whether the XML is valid.

Comment: Thanks Fabian.  Unfortunately, those nodes are for Lightspeed, so that's likely why you got the error.  I'm still investigating.